# Uploading multiple photos. Storing pictures on different servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upload

I want to create a site the ability to upload multiple pictures (at a time from 1 to 20, no more than 10-20 MB each).

Choose between Paperclip and CarrierWave. However, the question is the organization of storage (decided to keep the files in the filesystem, and the database only way for them).

1) I would like to dedicate to the image on a separate server subdomain such img.my_site.com. However, all the files loaded at once in **public** folder. There is an option to create symlink, but how to combine the two servers (web app and images)?

2) If someone solved a similar problem, please, advise a simpler solution?

UPD 1: For mass upload I want use
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/